# Missing expression after ',' in pipeline element Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

```
$ScriptBlock = { Start-Process -FilePath "$env:SystemRoot\System32\control.exe" -ArgumentList ("intl.cpl,,`/f:`"C:\Packages\Locale.xml`"") -Wait -PassThru }
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
```

Any idea whts reason for error below

```
+ ... nv:SystemRoot\System32\control.exe" -ArgumentList ("intl.cpl,,`/f:`"C ...
+                                                                  ~
Missing expression after ',' in pipeline element.
```

[image: error]

Comment: Usually, putting each argument as an element in a string array to pass to `Argumentlist` has the best results -> `-ArgumentList 'intl.cpl','/f:"C:\Packages\Locale.xml"'`

Comment: Seems like some bad arguments. That error is being thrown because there's a comma following a comma. Other than that, try this: `@('intl.cpl','/f:"C:\Packages\Locale.xml"')`

Answer (score 0):

`-ArgumentList` expects an array of strings.

Add a `@` prior to `(` and make sure each argument is separated with a `,`, i.e.

```
@("intl.cpl",,"`/f:`"C:\Packages\Locale.xml`"")
```